# dismissViewControllerAnimated mysteriously working for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiviewcontroller, dismiss

So I have an iPhone app that picks and image and then a popover comes up. You can can choose to cancel the popover which dismisses the popover and is what the following method does. When I test my app I can pick an image from the photo library, have the image picker be dismissed, but then the imagePicker comes back up. However, when I test my app, the following method's comment's are not being printed and I didn't implement a dimiss call elsewhere so how is it possible that this is happening???

```
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel called for iPad");
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel called for iPhone");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

[picker release];
[self pickImage];
}
```

Code used to present the view controller:

```
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0: { //photo library
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
                if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
                    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
                }
                else {
                    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
                    popoverController.delegate = self;
                    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake( 250, -50, 320, 480 )
                                                       inView:[self view]
                                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                                     animated:YES];
                }
            }
            else {
                [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE completion:nil];
            }
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Photo library is empty or unavailable" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate on your image picker controller?

Comment: yep I have added that code above.

Comment: Have you tried using breakpoints to determine if your "imagePickerControllerDidCancel" method is being called at all?

Comment: what does [self pickImage] method do? Maybe you're presenting controller 2 times?

Comment: @QuinnLiu try out my answer and let me know mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code for iphone and then check

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try out this one

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

OR in `imagePickerControllerDidCancel:` method like bellow...

```
- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];
        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];        
}
```

Comment: @QuinnLiu try out my above answer and let me know if any problem.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[self pickImage];

in

```
-(void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad ) {
    if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel called for iPad");
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
}
else {
    NSLog(@"imagePickerControllerDidCancel called for iPhone");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

[picker release];
[self pickImage];
}
```